# How to detect if the CMake script is being run in MSYS2 environment?

Tags: cmake, msys2

I want to detect if the `CMakeLists.txt` is being summoned inside an MSYS2 environment/shell:

```
$ uname
MSYS_NT-10.0-18363
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40152725/4999991) I have tried:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(test_cmake)

if(MSYS) # yes I have also tried MSYS2 with the same result!
    message("This is MSYS")
else()
    message("This is not MSYS")
endif()
```

which returns the same result `This is not MSYS` both in Windows cmd and MSYS2 shell. I'm not actually surprised because MSYS2 and MSYS are two different beasts! Also from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160459/4999991), I tried:

```
message(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME})
```

which both in cmd and MSYS2 returns `Windows`! I would appreciate it if you could help me know how I can detect if the `cmake` command is being run from inside an MSYS2 shell. Thanks for your support in advance.

**P.S.1.** As a personal note for myself, [this](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake) and [this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Write-Platform-Checks) seem like good sources to look into.

**P.S.2** Strangely enough the command

```
message(${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME})
```

also returns `Windows` while on my MSYS2, according to [the docuemntation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME.html), it must return the result of `uname -s`!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I know where the problem comes from. As I also had [other issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60747538/4999991) earlier, the `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake` caused this problem. So I uninstalled it and installed the `msys/cmake` package. Now:

- `if(MSYS)` retruns `TRUE`
- `message(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME})` --> `MSYS`
- `message(${CMAKE_SYSTEM})` --> `MSYS-3.0.7-338.x86_64`
- `message(${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME})` --> `MSYS`

one caveat is that now you have to specify the path to the make tool by `-D CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:path=mingw32-make`

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be a better answer, but you can use the output from `uname` you presented:

```
execute_process(COMMAND uname OUTPUT_VARIABLE uname)
if (uname MATCHES "^MSYS")
```

Comment: still not detecting as `uname MATCHES "^MSYS"` seem to return `false`. would you please expand your if-statement? I have a suspicion that I don't know how to write that part.

Comment: I'm also concerned if we can distinguish between MSYS and MSYS2 given that the `uname` results don't say anything about being MSYS2. We might need to parse the whole return value.

Comment: It works for me, as in `uname` outputs `Linux` and I substitute `"^MSYS"` for `"^Lin"` and it matches successfully. So parse the whole output. How would you detect if you are on MSYS and on MSYS2?

Comment: `uname` on MSYS2 actually gives `MINGW64_NT-10.0-19043`!

Answer (score 1):

What I found most reliable, considering all answers and comments up to now, and building upon them, is using

```
execute_process(COMMAND uname OUTPUT_VARIABLE uname)
if (uname MATCHES "^MSYS" OR uname MATCHES "^MINGW")
    message("This is MSYS")
else()
    message("This is not MSYS")
endif()
```

In my msys2, this is what I see in `cmake`

```
message("a ${MSYS}")                    --> prints a, MSYS does not exist 
message("a ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")       --> prints a, CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME does not exist 
message("a ${CMAKE_SYSTEM}")            --> prints a, CMAKE_SYSTEM does not exist 
message("a ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME}")  --> prints a MSYS_NT-10.0-19044-WOW64, could be used
```

and

```
$ uname
MSYS_NT-10.0-19044-WOW64
```

Answer (score 1):

With MSYS2 default installation, when running MSYS2 MinGW x64, I have:

```
$ uname
MINGW64_NT-10.0-19042
```

So we can simply use https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/MINGW.html

```
if (MINGW)
   message("This is MSYS2")
else()
    message("This is not MSYS2")
endif()
```